# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString') at node_modules\webpack\lib\cache\PackFileCacheStrategy.js:1243

Tags: reactjs, webpack

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString')
at C:\Users\Needa Ansari\Desktop\React Projects\myjewel\node_modules\webpack\lib\cache\PackFileCacheStrategy.js:1243:53
at async Promise.all (index 42)

> Node.js v18.15.0[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2v0d.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VzYK.png)

how to resolve this error? what is the error about

```
store(identifier, etag, data) {
        if (this.readonly) return Promise.resolve();
        // the error is in the line below
        return this._getPack().then(pack => {
            pack.set(identifier, etag === null? null : etag.toString(), data);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
etag === null || undefined ? null : etag.toString()
```

Comment: This error occured in  the PackFileCacheStrategy.js of webpack of node_modules. Trying this gave me the same error

Answer (score 0):

try
`typeof etag === 'undefined' ? null : etag.toString()`

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'toString') at C:\Users\User\Desktop\React Projects\myjewel\node_modules\webpack\lib\cache\PackFileCacheStrategy.js:1243:67 at async Promise.all (index 1)     Now tried this----     typeof etag === 'undefined' || 'null' ? null : etag.toString()        .Still the server has not started

Answer (score 0):

There is no sense in editing PackFileCacheStrategy.js, as it is node_modules file and would be overwritten. Try following solutions from this discussion
https://github.com/webpack/webpack/discussions/17101.
For me upgrading semantic-ui-css worked.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34885999)

Answer (score 0):

I imported image in a css file of React App. That's why it was showing error. Removing the line used for importing the image, solved my error.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same error after updating a project from Node v14 to v20. I ended up uninstalling semantic-ui-react and semantic-ui-css and then reinstalling them with npm.